# Reset fieldset and legend in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, legend, fieldset

I really like the default look of fieldset and legend in plain ole HTML.

Q: Is there any way to tell jQuery Mobile to display fieldset and legend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fieldset {
    border:2px solid cornflowerblue !important;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding:1em !important;
    margin-bottom:1em !important;
}
legend {
    padding-left:1em !important;
    padding-right:1em !important;
}
```

Comment: The !important attribute overrides jQuery Mobiles's css.